# Mongoose- Group By And Populate : Get unique list of users a person had been talking to like whatsapp first screen where you have all previous users

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have been working on a chat app and i need to display the list of the users having conversation with the a user. more like the [first screen of the whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q7tA.jpg) where you have the list of all users who texted you.

my messagesSchema is as follows:

```
from : {type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Users"},
to : {type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Users"},
messageType : String,
messageContent :String,
images : [Object],
poster : Object,
status : String,
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

i am using nodejs and i have tried so many agrregations, group by and other mongoose queries but fail

please help me with the query to get all the different unique users a person have been having a conversation with their single last message and populate the 'to' and 'from'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("100000000000000000000000"),
    "from": ObjectId("100000000000000000000000"),
    "to": ObjectId("200000000000000000000000"),
    "date": ISODate("2021-09-03T11:23:25.184Z"),
    "messageContent": "111"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("200000000000000000000000"),
    "from": ObjectId("200000000000000000000000"),
    "to": ObjectId("100000000000000000000000"),
    "date": ISODate("2021-09-02T11:23:25.184Z"),
    "messageContent": "222"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("300000000000000000000000"),
    "from": ObjectId("300000000000000000000000"),
    "to": ObjectId("100000000000000000000000"),
    "date": ISODate("2021-09-04T11:23:25.184Z"),
    "messageContent": "333"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("400000000000000000000000"),
    "from": ObjectId("300000000000000000000000"),
    "to": ObjectId("400000000000000000000000"),
    "date": ISODate("2021-09-05T11:23:25.184Z"),
    "messageContent": "444"
  }
]
```

Aggregate: (you are `ObjectId("100000000000000000000000")`)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$or": [
        { "from": ObjectId("100000000000000000000000") },
        { "to": ObjectId("100000000000000000000000") }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      whom: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: [ "$from", "$to" ],
            as: "i",
            cond: { $ne: [ "$$i", ObjectId("100000000000000000000000") ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      date: 1,
      messageContent: 1,
      to: 1,
      from: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { "date": -1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$whom",
      date: { "$first": "$date" },
      message: { "$first": "$messageContent" },
      to: { "$first": "$to" },
      from: { "$first": "$from" }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("300000000000000000000000"),
    "date": ISODate("2021-09-04T11:23:25.184Z"),
    "message": "333"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("200000000000000000000000"),
    "date": ISODate("2021-09-03T11:23:25.184Z"),
    "message": "222"
  }
]
```

**Example: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ceS6H6ccdvE)**

Comment: Hey...can you also modify it a little...how to get other columns in the result like the 'to' field and 'from' field and populating the 'to' and 'from' fields

Comment: I modify my ans, add `to` and `from`

Comment: incorrect Results..... when i am the sender the to and from are same....... i also did that but got this error

Comment: actually the main thing here is i have to get the profile image and name of the contact. so populating only the `_id` will get the work done

Comment: i update it again

Comment: perfect.... Just need to populate the `whom` or `_id`.....  can we do that in the same query?... i dont want to run a seperate query which  populate the `_id` field

Comment: btw thanks man... i appreciate your help

Comment: the result field is `_id` 、`date`、`from`、`message`、`to`, which one you want to remove ?

Comment: I want to populate the `_id` with $lookup from the USERS table so i can get the name and profile pic of the other user

Comment: do you understand what i am saying?
we get the messages of the other users with their id in `_id`
now we need to populate the _id so i can get their name and profilePicture from the USERS table.
now we have `_id`, `message`,`date`,`to`,`from` 
now we need to get two more fields (`name`,`profilePicture`) from the USERS table in the result based on the `_id`

Comment: Sure you can use `$lookup` in the same "query", just add it to the buttom aggregate.

Comment: hey could you please add $lookup to the query?